# div display:none when 'word' is in the url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tried googling around and I can't seem to be able to find if this is even possible. I use IPBoard and due to their most recent IPS4 update i can no longer just change the homepage i have to add divs to global layout meaning they appear on every page, which aren’t what I’m wanting.

So i was wondering if it would be possible via `JavaScript` of `jquery` to hide the div when url contains a word.

Example div would appear on home 'domain.com/’, but not on 'domain/hidden/'
If this isn’t possible then let me know and I’ll remove it, I’m reasonably new to `JavaScript` and jquery I only really know html/css so please be patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("my-word") !== -1) {
    $("#my-div").hide()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits in the original post, this method doesn't work.

the url is Domain.com/forums
and the div is #test

so i put forums in replace of "my-word" and #test in replace of "#my-div" and the div still appears on the URL Domain.com/forums

Comment: One second i'll mix and match my code with this, i'll edit this comment if i get it working or not

EDIT:

So i mixed and matched the code and it works however it pops up at the top as a notification, anyway to disable that ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you meant

Comment: not sure why but now that iv'e put the code in it pops up saying:

Domain.com says:
domain.com

Comment: can't edit last comment for some reason.... but iv'e fixed my issue thanks dude it works!